# How to reschedule the job execution interval in Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am a bit new to Quartz. Is there a way to update the job execution interval for an already submitted Quartz job? Does this interval get updated immediately? Do you have to start the job once again after rescheduling it?

I found the following link but I don't know which libraries is the code referring to since my quartz jars don't contain some of the classes used in the link. Also, where did the triggerKey method come from? Is this some kind of a static import?

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/cookbook/UpdateTrigger.html

I want to update the job execution interval to a very large number in one of my JUnit test cases since I don't want the job to interfere with the state of the class under test. Once the test case completes, I want to reset the the job execution interval to the actual value that will be used in production

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to reschedule the job by creating a new trigger.

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    Trigger newTrigger = what_ever_you_want;
    Trigger oldTrigger = context.getTrigger();
    Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
}
```

This will replace the same job with a new trigger fire time.

Comment: then what happen to old trigger ..it will die automatically ?

Comment: @MiDhuN rescheduleJob deletes it using its key.

Comment: With this way seems like  i have to wait till job execute this method.Why don't u create separate method for rescheduling as mentioned above link from quartz docs .

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand on [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188764/kris) and [Alex Mi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925356/alex-mi) answers.

Below is an example of a multi-instance Spring Boot application that launches a cron job.
The Job must be running on only one of the instances.
The configuration of each instance must be the same.
If a job crashes, it should try to restart 3 times with a delay of 5 minutes * number of restart attempts.
If the job still crashes after 3 restarts, the default cron for our job trigger should be set.

**We will use Quartz in cluster mode:**

Deps:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz")
```

*Out job:*

```kotlin
@Component
@Profile("quartz")
class SomeJob(
    private val someService: SomeService
) : QuartzJobBean() {
    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeJob::class.java)
    
    override fun executeInternal(jobExecutionContext: JobExecutionContext) {
        try {
            log.info("Doing awesome work...")
            someService.work()
            if ((1..10).random() >= 5) throw RuntimeException("Something went wrong...")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw JobExecutionException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Quartz configuration (more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule)):

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Profile("quartz")
class JobConfig {
    //JobDetail for our job
    @Bean
    fun someJobDetail(): JobDetail {
        return JobBuilder
            .newJob(SomeJob::class.java).withIdentity("SomeJob")
            .withDescription("Some job")
            //If we want the job to be launched after the application instance crashes at the 
            //next launch
            .requestRecovery(true)
            .storeDurably().build()
    }

    //Trigger
    @Bean
    fun someJobTrigger(someJobDetail: JobDetail): Trigger {
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(someJobDetail)
            .withIdentity("SomeJobTrigger")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 4 L-1 * ? *"))
            .build()

    }

    //Otherwise, changing cron for an existing trigger will not work. (the old cron value will be stored in the database)
    @Bean
    fun scheduler(triggers: List<Trigger>, jobDetails: List<JobDetail>, factory: SchedulerFactoryBean): Scheduler {
        factory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true)
        val scheduler = factory.scheduler
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true)
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673572/spring-quartz-scheduler-race-condition
        factory.setTransactionManager(JdbcTransactionManager())
        rescheduleTriggers(triggers, scheduler)
        scheduler.start()
        return scheduler
    }

    private fun rescheduleTriggers(triggers: List<Trigger>, scheduler: Scheduler) {
        triggers.forEach {
            if (!scheduler.checkExists(it.key)) {
                scheduler.scheduleJob(it)
            } else {
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(it.key, it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add a listener to the scheduler:

```kotlin
@Component
@Profile("quartz")
class JobListenerConfig(
    private val schedulerFactory: SchedulerFactoryBean,
    private val jobListener: JobListener
) {
    @PostConstruct
    fun addListener() {
        schedulerFactory.scheduler.listenerManager.addJobListener(jobListener, KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobKey("SomeJob")))
    }
}
```

And now the most important - the logic of processing the execution of our job with listener:

```kotlin
@Profile("quartz")
class JobListener(
    //can be obtained from the execution context, but it can also be injected
    private val scheduler: Scheduler,
    private val triggers: List<Trigger>
): JobListenerSupport() {

    private lateinit var triggerCronMap: Map<String, String>

    @PostConstruct
    fun post(){
        //there will be no recovery triggers , only our self-written ones
        triggerCronMap = triggers.associate {
            it.key.name to (it as CronTrigger).cronExpression
        }
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        return "myJobListener"
    }


    override fun jobToBeExecuted(context: JobExecutionContext) {
        log.info("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} ready to start by trigger: ${context.trigger.key.name}")
    }


    override fun jobWasExecuted(context: JobExecutionContext, jobException: JobExecutionException?) {
        //you can use context.mergedJobDataMap
        val dataMap = context.trigger.jobDataMap
        val count = if (dataMap["count"] != null) dataMap.getIntValue("count") else {
            dataMap.putAsString("count", 1)
            1
        }
        //in the if block, you can add the condition && !context.trigger.key.name.startsWith("recover_") - in this case, the scheduler will not restart recover triggers if they fall during execution
        if (jobException != null ){
            if (count < 3) {
                log.warn("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} filed while execution. Restart attempts count: $count ")
                val oldTrigger = context.trigger
                var newTriggerName = context.trigger.key.name + "_retry"
                //in case such a trigger already exists
                context.scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(context.jobDetail.key)
                    .map { it.key.name }
                    .takeIf { it.contains(newTriggerName) }
                    ?.apply { newTriggerName += "_retry" }
                val newTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .forJob(context.jobDetail)
                    .withIdentity(newTriggerName, context.trigger.key.group)
                    //create a simple trigger that should be fired in 5 minutes * restart attempts
                    .startAt(Date.from(Instant.now().plus((5 * count).toLong(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES)))
                    .usingJobData("count", count + 1 )
                    .build()
                val date = scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.key, newTrigger)
                log.info("Rescheduling trigger: ${oldTrigger.key} to trigger: ${newTrigger.key}")
            } else {
                log.warn("Reach max count of restarts: $count. Remove all triggers for job: ${context.trigger.jobKey.name} and schedule default trigger for it: ${context.trigger.key.name.split("_")[0]}")
                recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context)
            }
        } else if (count > 1) {
            recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context)
        }
        else {
            log.info("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} completed successfully")
        }
        context.scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(context.trigger.jobKey).forEach {
            log.info("Trigger with key: ${it.key} for job: ${context.trigger.jobKey.name} will start at ${it.nextFireTime ?: it.startTime}")
        }
    }

    private fun recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context: JobExecutionContext) {
        val clone = context.jobDetail.clone() as JobDetail
        val defaultTriggerName = context.trigger.key.name.split("_")[0]
        //Recovery triggers should not be rescheduled
        if (!triggerCronMap.contains(defaultTriggerName)) return
        scheduler.deleteJob(clone.key)
        scheduler.addJob(clone, true)
        scheduler.scheduleJob(
            TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .forJob(clone)
                .withIdentity(defaultTriggerName)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(triggerCronMap[defaultTriggerName]))
                .usingJobData("count", 1)
                .startAt(Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(5)))
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

Last but not least: **application.yaml**

```yaml
spring:
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc #Database Mode
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never #Do not initialize table structure
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO #Default hostname and timestamp generate instance ID, which can be any string, but must be the only corresponding qrtz_scheduler_state INSTANCE_NAME field for all dispatchers
            #instanceName: clusteredScheduler #quartzScheduler
          jobStore:
#            a few problems with the two properties below: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28758#issuecomment-974628989 & https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/284
#            class: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore #Persistence Configuration
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate #We only make database-specific proxies for databases
#            useProperties: true #Indicates that JDBC JobStore stores all values in JobDataMaps as strings, so more complex objects can be stored as name-value pairs rather than serialized in BLOB columns.In the long run, this is safer because you avoid serializing non-String classes to BLOB class versions.
            tablePrefix: scam_quartz.QRTZ_  #Database Table Prefix
            misfireThreshold: 60000 #The number of milliseconds the dispatcher will "tolerate" a Trigger to pass its next startup time before being considered a "fire".The default value (if you do not enter this property in the configuration) is 60000 (60 seconds).
            clusterCheckinInterval: 5000 #Set the frequency (in milliseconds) of this instance'checkin'* with other instances of the cluster.Affects the speed of detecting failed instances.
            isClustered: true #Turn on Clustering
          threadPool: #Connection Pool
            class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
            threadCount: 3
            threadPriority: 1
            threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
```

[Here](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore) official scripts for database (use liquibase or flyway)
More information:
[About quartz](https://www.baeldung.com/quartz)
[spring boot using quartz in cluster mode](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-using-quartz-in-mode-cluster-e1d71e4af4b9)
[One more article](https://habr.com/ru/companies/surfstudio/articles/685980)
[Cluster effectively quartz](https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-cluster-effectively-quartz-jobs-9b097f5e1191)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a static method triggerKey() somewhere in the Quartz library. However, I managed to reschedule an existing Quartz job (using Quartz 2.3.2) without using this (potential) method, but rather using the TriggerKey class as follows:

```
    boolean updateExisting = true; // try it also with false
    int aveId = 1234; // change it as you wish
    java.util.Date closeDate = new java.util.Date(); // change it as you wish

    SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory("... /quartz_priority.properties");
    Scheduler scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

    TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("trigger" + aveId, "group1");

    if (updateExisting) {
        Trigger oldTrigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey);
        TriggerBuilder oldTriggerBuilder = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

        Trigger newTrigger = oldTriggerBuilder.startAt(closeDate).build();
        scheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerKey, newTrigger);

    } else {
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(triggerKey).startAt(closeDate).build();

        // Define job instance
        JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(<YOUR_JOB_CLASS_NAME>.class).withIdentity("job" + aveId, "group1").build();

        JobDataMap map = job1.getJobDataMap();
        map.put(<PARAMETER_NAME>, aveId);

        // Schedule the job with the trigger
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job1, trigger);
    }
```