# Spring and scheduled tasks on multiple instances

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jobs, job-scheduling

We have a Spring Boot application, and have scheduled tasks.

We want to deploy our application on multiple servers, so will be multiple instances of application.

How to configure Spring to run scheduled tasks only on specified servers?

Comment: could be feasible using config files from outside the application.

Comment: https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock is a decent framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Scheduled Task running in clustered environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288810/spring-scheduled-task-running-in-clustered-environment)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is a very wide topic. And there are many options to achieve this.

1. You can configure your application to have multiple profiles. For example use another profile 'cron' . And start your application on only one server with this profile. So for example, on a production environment you have three servers (S1, S2, S3), then you could run on S1 with profile prod and cron(`-Dspring.profiles.active=prod,cron`). And on S2 and S3 just use prod profile(`-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`).

   And in code, you can use `@Profile("cron")` on scheduler classes. This way it will be executed only when cron profile is active
2. Use a distributed lock. If you have Zookeeper in your environment, you can use this to achieve distributed locking system.
3. You can use some database(mysql) and create a sample code to get a lock on one of the table and add an entry. And whichever instance gets the lock, will make an entry in this database and will execute the cron job. You need to
   put a check in your code, if `getLock()` is successfull only then proceed with execution. Mysql has utilities like `LOCK TABLES`, which you could use to get away with concurrent read/writes.
4. Use [Spring shedlock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock). This library aims to solve this problem quite elegantly and with minimum code. Have a look at an example [here](https://baeldung.com/shedlock-spring)

personally I would say, option 2 or option 4 is the best of all.

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran please can you explain option 1 in depth by giving some example. That where i need to set this -Dspring.profiles.active=prod,cron means in which file etc.

Comment: Hi @Bharti Rawat "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod,cron" these are JVM parameters given to your application when application runs

Answer (score 35):

The **Spring - ShedLock** project is specifically created to achieve this.

Dependency -

```
<groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
<artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
```

Configuration -

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT30S")
```

Implementation -

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * * ?")
@SchedulerLock(name = "AnyUniqueName", 
  lockAtLeastForString = "PT5M", lockAtMostForString = "PT10M")
public void scheduledTask() {
    // ...
}
```

This setup will make sure that exactly one instance should run the scheduled task.

If you want only a specific instance should run the Scheduler task,

You need to config your scheduler to use the properties file and control the Scheduler switch like this -

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(
  value = "scheduling.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true
)
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT30S")
public class SchedulingConfig {
```

Now, you need to provide a property `scheduling.enabled = true` in your `application.properties` file, for the instance from which you want Schedular to be run.

Follow this [link](https://rieckpil.de/lock-scheduled-tasks-with-shedlock-and-spring-boot/) for complete implementation.

Answer (score 7):

One of the best options - use Quartz scheduler with clustering.
It's simple, just:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz")
```

And configure jobs for quartz with spring (see [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule))

Clustering configs in application.yaml:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource: ... # define jdbc datasource
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc # Database Mode
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never # For clustering do not initialize table structure
    properties:
      org.quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO #Default hostname and timestamp generate instance ID, which can be any string, but must be the only corresponding qrtz_scheduler_state INSTANCE_NAME field for all dispatchers
            #instanceName: clusteredScheduler #quartzScheduler
          jobStore:
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX #Persistence Configuration
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate #We only make database-specific proxies for databases
            useProperties: true #Indicates that JDBC JobStore stores all values in JobDataMaps as strings, so more complex objects can be stored as name-value pairs rather than serialized in BLOB columns.In the long run, this is safer because you avoid serializing non-String classes to BLOB class versions.
            tablePrefix: QRTZ_  #Database Table Prefix
            misfireThreshold: 60000 #The number of milliseconds the dispatcher will "tolerate" a Trigger to pass its next startup time before being considered a "fire".The default value (if you do not enter this property in the configuration) is 60000 (60 seconds).
            clusterCheckinInterval: 5000 #Set the frequency (in milliseconds) of this instance'checkin'* with other instances of the cluster.Affects the speed of detecting failed instances.
            isClustered: true #Turn on Clustering
          threadPool: #Connection Pool
            class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
            threadCount: 10
            threadPriority: 5
            threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
```

Attention on `initialize-schema: never` - you need to initialize it by yourself for cluster mode

See official scripts: https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore
And you can use it through liquibase/flyway/etc, but remove `DROP ...` queries! That's why in cluster we don't initialize schema automatically.

See [quartz docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html)
See [spring boot docs quartz](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.quartz)
See [article with example](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-using-quartz-in-mode-cluster-e1d71e4af4b9)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do it with Spring is using an environment variable and Value annotation:

1 - Get the environment variable with Value annotation in your class:

```
@Value("${TASK_ENABLED}")
private boolean taskEnabled;
```

2 - Check the taskEnabled value to execute the task:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 50000)
public void myTask() {
  if (this.taskEnabled) {
    //do stuff here...
  }
}
```

3 - Set the correct environment variable per server:

false:

```
java -DTASK_ENABLED=0 -jar software.jar
```

or

true:

```
java -DTASK_ENABLED=1 -jar software.jar
```

**Example with a global configuration class**

To use a global configuration class, you should say to spring it's a component with a @Component and annotate a set method to pass the value to static field.

1 - Create the configuration class with static fields:

```
@Component
public class AppConfiguration {

  public static boolean taskEnabled;

  @Value("${TASK_ENABLED}")
  public void setTaskEnabled(boolean taskEnabled) {
    this.taskEnabled = taskEnabled;
  }
}
```

2 - Check the taskEnabled value to execute the task:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 50000)
public void myTask() {
  if (AppConfiguration.taskEnabled) {
    //do stuff here...
  }
}
```

3 - Set the correct environment variable per server:

false:

```
java -DTASK_ENABLED=0 -jar software.jar
```

or

true:

```
java -DTASK_ENABLED=1 -jar software.jar
```

Comment: may is it possible somehow to make this global? I do not want tot put this if in every method

Comment: Yep ! You could create a configuration class with static fields for example, and put this configuration there, but to do that with Spring you should do some little things, as say to Spring that your configuration class is a Component and use a set method to pass the value for your static fiel, I will edit my answer with a example.

Comment: But you still need to put the if in every method, i just want to put in configuration shedulling.enabled=false and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I think the help you need is in one of the answers from another post.

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65551473/4147392

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution can be you can use different properties files for different instances. Here are the steps

1. Annotate your scheduler class with `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "enable-scheduler", havingValue = "true")`
2. Add a boolean in properties file `enable-scheduler=true`
3. Now for any instance use `enable-scheduler=true` and for any other ones use `enable-scheduler=false` in your properties file.

Example:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "enable-scheduler", havingValue = "true")
public class AnyScheduler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private final AnyService service;

    @Autowired
    public AnyScheduler(AnyService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler-cron}")
    public void syncModifiedCve() {
        log.info("Scheduler started. . .");
        service.doTask();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same usecase but weren't allowed to use database.
Simple hack,just create a file at a shared location , the instance which is able to create the file will run the scheduled process.

```
File file =new File(path);
if(file.createNewFile()){
    //run task
}
```

You can also add a random sleep time before creating file.

```
SecureRandom secureRandom =new SecureRandom();
Thread.sleep(secureRandom.nextInt(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70018820/19659058) by [Alexey Stepanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4906544/alexey-stepanov).
I hope this information will be useful.

Below is an example of a multi-instance Spring Boot application that launches a cron job.
The Job must be running on only one of the instances.
The configuration of each instance must be the same.
If a job crashes, it should try to restart 3 times with a delay of 5 minutes * number of restart attempts.
If the job still crashes after 3 restarts, the default cron for our job trigger should be set.

**We will use Quartz in cluster mode:**

Deps:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz")
```

At first, it is a bad idea to use Thread.sleep(600000) as said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4409263/19659058)
*Out job:*

```kotlin
@Component
@Profile("quartz")
class SomeJob(
    private val someService: SomeService
) : QuartzJobBean() {
    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeJob::class.java)
    
    override fun executeInternal(jobExecutionContext: JobExecutionContext) {
        try {
            log.info("Doing awesome work...")
            someService.work()
            if ((1..10).random() >= 5) throw RuntimeException("Something went wrong...")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw JobExecutionException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Quartz configuration (more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule)):

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Profile("quartz")
class JobConfig {
    //JobDetail for our job
    @Bean
    fun someJobDetail(): JobDetail {
        return JobBuilder
            .newJob(SomeJob::class.java).withIdentity("SomeJob")
            .withDescription("Some job")
            //If we want the job to be launched after the application instance crashes at the 
            //next launch
            .requestRecovery(true)
            .storeDurably().build()
    }

    //Trigger
    @Bean
    fun someJobTrigger(someJobDetail: JobDetail): Trigger {
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(someJobDetail)
            .withIdentity("SomeJobTrigger")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 4 L-1 * ? *"))
            .build()

    }

    //Otherwise, changing cron for an existing trigger will not work. (the old cron value will be stored in the database)
    @Bean
    fun scheduler(triggers: List<Trigger>, jobDetails: List<JobDetail>, factory: SchedulerFactoryBean): Scheduler {
        factory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true)
        val scheduler = factory.scheduler
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true)
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673572/spring-quartz-scheduler-race-condition
        factory.setTransactionManager(JdbcTransactionManager())
        rescheduleTriggers(triggers, scheduler)
        scheduler.start()
        return scheduler
    }

    private fun rescheduleTriggers(triggers: List<Trigger>, scheduler: Scheduler) {
        triggers.forEach {
            if (!scheduler.checkExists(it.key)) {
                scheduler.scheduleJob(it)
            } else {
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(it.key, it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add a listener to the scheduler:

```kotlin
@Component
@Profile("quartz")
class JobListenerConfig(
    private val schedulerFactory: SchedulerFactoryBean,
    private val jobListener: JobListener
) {
    @PostConstruct
    fun addListener() {
        schedulerFactory.scheduler.listenerManager.addJobListener(jobListener, KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobKey("SomeJob")))
    }
}
```

And now the most important - the logic of processing the execution of our job with listener:

```kotlin
@Profile("quartz")
class JobListener(
    //can be obtained from the execution context, but it can also be injected
    private val scheduler: Scheduler,
    private val triggers: List<Trigger>
): JobListenerSupport() {

    private lateinit var triggerCronMap: Map<String, String>

    @PostConstruct
    fun post(){
        //there will be no recovery triggers , only our self-written ones
        triggerCronMap = triggers.associate {
            it.key.name to (it as CronTrigger).cronExpression
        }
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        return "myJobListener"
    }


    override fun jobToBeExecuted(context: JobExecutionContext) {
        log.info("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} ready to start by trigger: ${context.trigger.key.name}")
    }


    override fun jobWasExecuted(context: JobExecutionContext, jobException: JobExecutionException?) {
        //you can use context.mergedJobDataMap
        val dataMap = context.trigger.jobDataMap
        val count = if (dataMap["count"] != null) dataMap.getIntValue("count") else {
            dataMap.putAsString("count", 1)
            1
        }
        //in the if block, you can add the condition && !context.trigger.key.name.startsWith("recover_") - in this case, the scheduler will not restart recover triggers if they fall during execution
        if (jobException != null ){
            if (count < 3) {
                log.warn("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} filed while execution. Restart attempts count: $count ")
                val oldTrigger = context.trigger
                var newTriggerName = context.trigger.key.name + "_retry"
                //in case such a trigger already exists
                context.scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(context.jobDetail.key)
                    .map { it.key.name }
                    .takeIf { it.contains(newTriggerName) }
                    ?.apply { newTriggerName += "_retry" }
                val newTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .forJob(context.jobDetail)
                    .withIdentity(newTriggerName, context.trigger.key.group)
                    //create a simple trigger that should be fired in 5 minutes * restart attempts
                    .startAt(Date.from(Instant.now().plus((5 * count).toLong(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES)))
                    .usingJobData("count", count + 1 )
                    .build()
                val date = scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.key, newTrigger)
                log.warn("Rescheduling trigger: ${oldTrigger.key} to trigger: ${newTrigger.key}")
            } else {
                log.warn("The maximum number of restarts has been reached. Restart attempts: $count")
                recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context)
            }
        } else if (count > 1) {
            recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context)
        }
        else {
            log.info("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} completed successfully")
        }
        context.scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(context.trigger.jobKey).forEach {
            log.info("Trigger with key: ${it.key} for job: ${context.trigger.jobKey.name} will start at ${it.nextFireTime ?: it.startTime}")
        }
    }

    private fun recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context: JobExecutionContext) {
        val clone = context.jobDetail.clone() as JobDetail
        val defaultTriggerName = context.trigger.key.name.split("_")[0]
        //Recovery triggers should not be rescheduled
        if (!triggerCronMap.contains(defaultTriggerName)) {
            log.warn("This trigger: ${context.trigger.key.name} for job: ${context.trigger.jobKey.name} is not self-written trigger. It can be recovery trigger or whatever. This trigger must not be recheduled.")
            return
        }
        log.warn("Remove all triggers for job: ${context.trigger.jobKey.name} and schedule default trigger for it: $defaultTriggerName")
        scheduler.deleteJob(clone.key)
        scheduler.addJob(clone, true)
        scheduler.scheduleJob(
            TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .forJob(clone)
                .withIdentity(defaultTriggerName)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(triggerCronMap[defaultTriggerName]))
                .usingJobData("count", 1)
                .startAt(Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(5)))
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

Last but not least: **application.yaml**

```yaml
spring:
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc #Database Mode
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never #Do not initialize table structure
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO #Default hostname and timestamp generate instance ID, which can be any string, but must be the only corresponding qrtz_scheduler_state INSTANCE_NAME field for all dispatchers
            #instanceName: clusteredScheduler #quartzScheduler
          jobStore:
#            a few problems with the two properties below: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28758#issuecomment-974628989 & https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/284
#            class: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore #Persistence Configuration
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate #We only make database-specific proxies for databases
#            useProperties: true #Indicates that JDBC JobStore stores all values in JobDataMaps as strings, so more complex objects can be stored as name-value pairs rather than serialized in BLOB columns.In the long run, this is safer because you avoid serializing non-String classes to BLOB class versions.
            tablePrefix: my_quartz.QRTZ_  #Database Table Prefix
            misfireThreshold: 60000 #The number of milliseconds the dispatcher will "tolerate" a Trigger to pass its next startup time before being considered a "fire".The default value (if you do not enter this property in the configuration) is 60000 (60 seconds).
            clusterCheckinInterval: 5000 #Set the frequency (in milliseconds) of this instance'checkin'* with other instances of the cluster.Affects the speed of detecting failed instances.
            isClustered: true #Turn on Clustering
          threadPool: #Connection Pool
            class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
            threadCount: 3
            threadPriority: 1
            threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
```

[Here](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore) official scripts for database (use liquibase or flyway)
More information:
[About quartz](https://www.baeldung.com/quartz)
[spring boot using quartz in cluster mode](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-using-quartz-in-mode-cluster-e1d71e4af4b9)
[One more article](https://habr.com/ru/companies/surfstudio/articles/685980)
[Cluster effectively quartz](https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-cluster-effectively-quartz-jobs-9b097f5e1191)