# How to control tenant based job execution across multiple instances of azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Requirement is -

1. Currently we are having one instance of app-service in which spring scheduled batch jobs are running which are reading, processing and writing records for multiple tenants.
2. We need to have multiple instances of the same app-service but need some logic to control the job execution per tenant on across instances.
3. Is there any way to know how many instances are there of current app-service in azure.

Comment: Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49533618/15997690)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT Thanks for the suggestion but we are not looking to implement any locking system. Rather, just wanted to know if we are running multiple instances of Spring boot-Spring batch application, then is there any way to restrict one tenant to run the scheduled job on same instance and do not distribute the request across instances.