# How to maintain unique records in DB table with multiple instances of SpringBoot application

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a scheduler which polls data in every 4 hours and inserts into table based upon certain logic.
I have also used `@Transactional` annotation and also I am checking every time whether data already exists in the table or not.
If the record does not exist, it will insert. When I am multiple instances of SpringBoot application, each instance runs the scheduler and some data not all get duplicated.
It means I found that table contains duplicate record. The table where I am inserting is an existing table of the application and few columns have not been defined with unique
constraints. Please suggest me how I can maintain unique records in the database table even if scheduler runs from multiple instances. I am using **Postgresql** and **SpringBoot**.

Answer (score 3):

So, the direct answer to you question is to have unique identifier for each record in your table. Unique id from external API will be a perfect match. If you don't have one - you can calculate it manually.
Consider an example:

```
@Entity @Table
public class Person {
    private String fieldOne;
    private String fieldTwo;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String uniqueId;
    
    //in case you have to generate uniqueId manually
    public static Person fromExternalApi(String fieldOne, String fieldTwo) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.fieldOne = fieldOne;
        person.fieldTwo = fieldTwo;
        person.uniqueId = fieldOne + fieldTwo;
    }
}
```

Then you will have unique index on DB side based on `uniqueId` field, and DB prevent you from duplicates.

Important - you can't use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

because it will generate new id each time you save object to DB. In you case you can save same object multiple times from different instances.

**But in you case I would suggest another solution.** The idea is to run scheduled task only once. And this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49533543/spring-and-scheduled-tasks-on-multiple-instances)

Comment: Seems to be useful Sir.