# Quartz retry job with exponentially increasing delay time strategy for trigger

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I use quartz in spring project. The idea is to create separate job for new income data, that was not delivered successfully to target service.

- To deliver data with exponentially increasing strategy I create job for next unsuccessful tries also. (It spams DB. It seems works, but can be better.)
- different my solution is to create repeatable crone based job, that scans DB data and loads only date should be handled now because time passed (in this case I have to manage a lot of on java part).

### Both ways can provide correct flow, but I prefer out the box solution.

I tried to manage `JobExecutionContext` of triggered job to use same `JobDetail` registering it in `quartzScheduler`. The idea was to update existing job with different trigger. But issue is quartz tries to create new job persisting it in DB.

```
org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job : 'digex-caas-securepay.b333e5bf-583f-4643-9ad7-ef4b913001f7', because one already exists with this identification.
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1113) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$2.executeVoid(JobStoreSupport.java:1067) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3765) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$VoidTransactionCallback.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:3763) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT.executeInLock(JobStoreCMT.java:245) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.storeJobAndTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1063) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:855) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:249) ~[quartz-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.incomm.ecomm.services.quartz.OrderQuartzJobScheduler.registerSecurePayPostServiceJob(OrderQuartzJobScheduler.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
```

### Questions are (please answer any):

- How to manage via quartz job trigger updates (in case it was not handled successfully - update trigger with different fired time)?
- How to manage via quartz job updates (in case it was not handled successfully - update job with new trigger)?
- How to register exponentially increasing delay time strategy for trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple answer is:

```
scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), trigger);
```

### Detailed answer is:

> - How to manage via quartz job trigger updates

scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), trigger);

> - How to manage via quartz job updates

It is not important any more in case trigger updated.

> - How to register exponentially increasing delay time strategy for trigger?

single trigger can be rescheduled with any different time. Time for next execution can be calculated using any implementation of `IntervalCalculationStrategy`.

### Example of reschedule the job:

The job and job details can be taken from `JobExecutionContext` but not necessary. Trigger can be connected to only one job, so it good enough for quartz specify `triggerKey` to be updated:

```
@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;
@Autowired
private IntervalCalculationStrategy intervalCalculation;

public <T extends QuartzJobBean> void registerSecurePayPostServiceJob(
    JobExecutionContext firedJobExecutionContext) {
  Optional<SimpleTriggerImpl> mutableTrigger =
      ofNullable(firedJobExecutionContext)
          .map(JobExecutionContext::getTrigger)
          .filter(SimpleTriggerImpl.class::isInstance)
          .map(SimpleTriggerImpl.class::cast);
  try {
    if (mutableTrigger.isPresent()) {
      SimpleTriggerImpl trigger = mutableTrigger.get();
      int nextAttemptNumber = trigger.getTimesTriggered();
      log.trace("trigger: {} fired [{}] times", trigger.getFullName(),
          trigger.getTimesTriggered());
      trigger.setStartTime(intervalCalculation.calculateNextTryDate(nextAttemptNumber));
      this.scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), trigger);
    }
  } catch (SchedulerException e) {
    log.error("job was not rescheduled <{}>", firedJobExecutionContext.getJobDetail(), e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- you can follow this approach (retry mechanism and can have no. of
  retries allowed) ref:
  [Quartz retry when failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408858/quartz-retry-when-failure)
- For each failure you can update the counter and send a email. So  you
  will be aware in the max try also is it successfully passed or not.
- If not later, you will have a dashboard to view the failed (includes
  no.of times its tried) and can run it manually mechanism.
- Instead of e.setRefireImmediately you can set a timeline ex. 120 mins later, schedule to run it i.e, based on the JobDataMap mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand on [Sergii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728095/sergii) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55206538/19659058) a little.

I hope this information will be useful for you (this is a copy of my answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75949972/19659058))

Below is an example of a multi-instance Spring Boot application that launches a cron job.
The Job must be running on only one of the instances.
The configuration of each instance must be the same.
If a job crashes, it should try to restart 3 times with a delay of 5 minutes * number of restart attempts.
If the job still crashes after 3 restarts, the default cron for our job trigger should be set.

**We will use Quartz in cluster mode:**

Deps:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz")
```

At first, it is a bad idea to use Thread.sleep(600000) as said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4409263/19659058)
*Out job:*

```kotlin
@Component
@Profile("quartz")
class SomeJob(
    private val someService: SomeService
) : QuartzJobBean() {
    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeJob::class.java)
    
    override fun executeInternal(jobExecutionContext: JobExecutionContext) {
        try {
            log.info("Doing awesome work...")
            someService.work()
            if ((1..10).random() >= 5) throw RuntimeException("Something went wrong...")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw JobExecutionException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Quartz configuration (more information [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule)):

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Profile("quartz")
class JobConfig {
    //JobDetail for our job
    @Bean
    fun someJobDetail(): JobDetail {
        return JobBuilder
            .newJob(SomeJob::class.java).withIdentity("SomeJob")
            .withDescription("Some job")
            //If we want the job to be launched after the application instance crashes at the 
            //next launch
            .requestRecovery(true)
            .storeDurably().build()
    }

    //Trigger
    @Bean
    fun someJobTrigger(someJobDetail: JobDetail): Trigger {
        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(someJobDetail)
            .withIdentity("SomeJobTrigger")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 4 L-1 * ? *"))
            .build()

    }

    //Otherwise, changing cron for an existing trigger will not work. (the old cron value will be stored in the database)
    @Bean
    fun scheduler(triggers: List<Trigger>, jobDetails: List<JobDetail>, factory: SchedulerFactoryBean): Scheduler {
        factory.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true)
        val scheduler = factory.scheduler
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true)
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673572/spring-quartz-scheduler-race-condition
        factory.setTransactionManager(JdbcTransactionManager())
        rescheduleTriggers(triggers, scheduler)
        scheduler.start()
        return scheduler
    }

    private fun rescheduleTriggers(triggers: List<Trigger>, scheduler: Scheduler) {
        triggers.forEach {
            if (!scheduler.checkExists(it.key)) {
                scheduler.scheduleJob(it)
            } else {
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(it.key, it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add a listener to the scheduler:

```kotlin
@Component
@Profile("quartz")
class JobListenerConfig(
    private val schedulerFactory: SchedulerFactoryBean,
    private val jobListener: JobListener
) {
    @PostConstruct
    fun addListener() {
        schedulerFactory.scheduler.listenerManager.addJobListener(jobListener, KeyMatcher.keyEquals(jobKey("SomeJob")))
    }
}
```

And now the most important - the logic of processing the execution of our job with listener:

```kotlin
@Profile("quartz")
class JobListener(
    //can be obtained from the execution context, but it can also be injected
    private val scheduler: Scheduler,
    private val triggers: List<Trigger>
): JobListenerSupport() {

    private lateinit var triggerCronMap: Map<String, String>

    @PostConstruct
    fun post(){
        //there will be no recovery triggers , only our self-written ones
        triggerCronMap = triggers.associate {
            it.key.name to (it as CronTrigger).cronExpression
        }
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        return "myJobListener"
    }


    override fun jobToBeExecuted(context: JobExecutionContext) {
        log.info("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} ready to start by trigger: ${context.trigger.key.name}")
    }


    override fun jobWasExecuted(context: JobExecutionContext, jobException: JobExecutionException?) {
        //you can use context.mergedJobDataMap
        val dataMap = context.trigger.jobDataMap
        val count = if (dataMap["count"] != null) dataMap.getIntValue("count") else {
            dataMap.putAsString("count", 1)
            1
        }
        //in the if block, you can add the condition && !context.trigger.key.name.startsWith("recover_") - in this case, the scheduler will not restart recover triggers if they fall during execution
        if (jobException != null ){
            if (count < 3) {
                log.warn("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} filed while execution. Restart attempts count: $count ")
                val oldTrigger = context.trigger
                var newTriggerName = context.trigger.key.name + "_retry"
                //in case such a trigger already exists
                context.scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(context.jobDetail.key)
                    .map { it.key.name }
                    .takeIf { it.contains(newTriggerName) }
                    ?.apply { newTriggerName += "_retry" }
                val newTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .forJob(context.jobDetail)
                    .withIdentity(newTriggerName, context.trigger.key.group)
                    //create a simple trigger that should be fired in 5 minutes * restart attempts
                    .startAt(Date.from(Instant.now().plus((5 * count).toLong(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES)))
                    .usingJobData("count", count + 1 )
                    .build()
                val date = scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.key, newTrigger)
                log.warn("Rescheduling trigger: ${oldTrigger.key} to trigger: ${newTrigger.key}")
            } else {
                log.warn("The maximum number of restarts has been reached. Restart attempts: $count")
                recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context)
            }
        } else if (count > 1) {
            recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context)
        }
        else {
            log.info("Job: ${context.jobDetail.key.name} completed successfully")
        }
        context.scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(context.trigger.jobKey).forEach {
            log.info("Trigger with key: ${it.key} for job: ${context.trigger.jobKey.name} will start at ${it.nextFireTime ?: it.startTime}")
        }
    }

    private fun recheduleWithDefaultTrigger(context: JobExecutionContext) {
        val clone = context.jobDetail.clone() as JobDetail
        val defaultTriggerName = context.trigger.key.name.split("_")[0]
        //Recovery triggers should not be rescheduled
        if (!triggerCronMap.contains(defaultTriggerName)) {
            log.warn("This trigger: ${context.trigger.key.name} for job: ${context.trigger.jobKey.name} is not self-written trigger. It can be recovery trigger or whatever. This trigger must not be recheduled.")
            return
        }
        log.warn("Remove all triggers for job: ${context.trigger.jobKey.name} and schedule default trigger for it: $defaultTriggerName")
        scheduler.deleteJob(clone.key)
        scheduler.addJob(clone, true)
        scheduler.scheduleJob(
            TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .forJob(clone)
                .withIdentity(defaultTriggerName)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(triggerCronMap[defaultTriggerName]))
                .usingJobData("count", 1)
                .startAt(Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(5)))
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```

Last but not least: **application.yaml**

```yaml
spring:
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc #Database Mode
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never #Do not initialize table structure
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO #Default hostname and timestamp generate instance ID, which can be any string, but must be the only corresponding qrtz_scheduler_state INSTANCE_NAME field for all dispatchers
            #instanceName: clusteredScheduler #quartzScheduler
          jobStore:
#            a few problems with the two properties below: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28758#issuecomment-974628989 & https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/284
#            class: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore #Persistence Configuration
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate #We only make database-specific proxies for databases
#            useProperties: true #Indicates that JDBC JobStore stores all values in JobDataMaps as strings, so more complex objects can be stored as name-value pairs rather than serialized in BLOB columns.In the long run, this is safer because you avoid serializing non-String classes to BLOB class versions.
            tablePrefix: scam_quartz.QRTZ_  #Database Table Prefix
            misfireThreshold: 60000 #The number of milliseconds the dispatcher will "tolerate" a Trigger to pass its next startup time before being considered a "fire".The default value (if you do not enter this property in the configuration) is 60000 (60 seconds).
            clusterCheckinInterval: 5000 #Set the frequency (in milliseconds) of this instance'checkin'* with other instances of the cluster.Affects the speed of detecting failed instances.
            isClustered: true #Turn on Clustering
          threadPool: #Connection Pool
            class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
            threadCount: 3
            threadPriority: 1
            threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true
```

[Here](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore) official scripts for database (use liquibase or flyway)
More information:
[About quartz](https://www.baeldung.com/quartz)
[spring boot using quartz in cluster mode](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-using-quartz-in-mode-cluster-e1d71e4af4b9)
[One more article](https://habr.com/ru/companies/surfstudio/articles/685980)
[Cluster effectively quartz](https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-cluster-effectively-quartz-jobs-9b097f5e1191)