# How to correctly re-schedule quartz job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I would like to re-schedule quartz job. I went through some of the answer raised (ex [How to reschedule the job execution interval in Quartz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257990/how-to-reschedule-the-job-execution-interval-in-quartz) ).

What I want to do is:

1. Schedule job to be run at a given time
2. Re-schedule the Job to be repeated minutely twice.

So in general, the job should be trigger 3 times.

My main class:

```
    public class Main{



          public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
                        .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

                    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
                        .withSchedule(
                                CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 41 16 1/1 * ? *"))
                        .build();

                    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
                    scheduler.start();
                    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
          }

}
```

and the Job class:

```
public class HelloJob implements Job{



    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {

                System.out.println("Hello Quartz!  " + context.getTrigger().toString());    
                Trigger newTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
                        .withSchedule(
                                SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatMinutelyForTotalCount(2))
                        .build();

                Trigger oldTrigger = context.getTrigger();
                Scheduler scheduler = null;
                try {
                    scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
                    scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);

                } catch (SchedulerException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
}
```

When I run the code it gives me:

```
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
Hello Quartz!  Trigger 'group1.dummyTriggerName':  triggerClass: 'org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl calendar: 'null' misfireInstruction: 0 nextFireTime: Sun Jun 02 16:42:00 CEST 2019
......
```

And this in the console is like repeating many times in each second and cannot stop. The original Trigger triggers as expected (this from Main class) but when rescheduled in HelloJob class it is going crazy.

I do not understand why it behaves like that. What am I doing wrong?